# AWS CDK Logging - after a cdk deploy, i get the error message : props.destination.bind is not a function

Tags: python, aws-cdk

Im using the following bit of code to create a log group and a subscription filter :

```
lo = logs_.LogGroup(self, 'LogGroup',  retention=logs_.RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK )

logs_.SubscriptionFilter(self, 'Subscription', 
    log_group=lo,
    destination=apiFunction,
    filter_pattern=logs_.FilterPattern.all_events()
)
```

however, I get the following error message when I attempt to deploy : "props.destination.bind is not a function"

Also, is this the correct way to create a cloud watch log ?  there is barely any python examples on how to create a cloud watch log

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the `apiFunction` object.

According to the [CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.ILogSubscriptionDestination.html), it must be one of the following objects: `KinesisDestination`, `LambdaDestination`, `CrossAccountDestination`.